# Masking an image using paths

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, mask, cgcontext

How do you mask an image using paths?
What I am trying to do is draw a line using `CGContextStrokePath` and show only those parts of a `CGLayerRef` which are under it. Also, how do you erase only those parts of the `CGLayerRef` 
which are under it?

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the docs for `CGContextSetBlendMode()`, especially when used with `kCGBlendModeClear`.